# texturing 2.8 cant see proportions and profile

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I need help with this problem, because when this is irreparably it would be a huge downside of 2.8 and a reason for me to change the program.

If I go into TexturePaint Mode my view looks like the first pic, but i prefer the look of the second picture (just like 2.79). But i cant figure out, how to do draw, meanwhile it looks like the second pic. And no i dont want to paint on the UV in the UV-Editor, I prefer to do it live on the object

[image: TexturePaint 2.8]

[image: Rendered View 2.8 (Eevee), similar to TexturePaint in 2.79]

Your help would mean such a big relief for a me, because like this it got almost impossible to paint complex objects like faces correctly.

Best regards, Marc

Answer (score 1):

As Jackdaw has already suggested in the **Overlays** menu lower the **Texture paint** **Opacity** value.

Note: In the image below the viewport shading is in Solid mode.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Explore the various settings for the viewport. It's way more capable now than it have ever been. To start with, you can change the view port engine to LookDev and adjust the Texture Paint Opacity in Overlays.

Comment: I think 'Explore the various settings' is a bit too much of a general answer. Ideally, answers should provide a specific solution that solves the problem.